Azure Function not returning TypedResults.Ok
I am trying to modernize a couple azure functions, and thought of integrating them with latest .NET Core types.
Here is a simple function:
[Function("Function")]
public IResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    return TypedResults.Ok(DateTime.Now);
}

I was expecting this to return, in this case the date. But instead response content is blank.
Preferably, it should also work with Task<IResult> but that doesn't work either.
Thanks

AFAIK, TypedResults is not customized with Azure Functions

AFAIK this is a expected behavior as TypedResults gives blank response in isolated azure functions and that is what I have received.  As of now .net 8 with Azure functions only uses isolated functions.
So, alternatively I would suggest you to use OkObjectResult :
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest r)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik");
    return new OkObjectResult(DateTime.Now);
}

Output:

